# How to use the functions Emgu.CV.QRCodeDetector.Detect and Emgu.CV.QRCodeDetector.Decode?

Tags: c#, opencv, qr-code, emgucv

I'm using Emgu CV v4.6 with C# 6.0 on Visual Studio. I need to scan a QR code using Emgu CV but I have no clue about how to use the functions [Emgu.CV.QRCodeDetector.Detect](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.3/document/html/1642139a-7e19-1759-4798-bdc6920cf46d.htm) and [Emgu.CV.QRCodeDetector.Decode](https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.5.3/document/html/d9611d23-cbe1-fc54-14f1-f7ca90dbc837.htm). In the documentation, it is said that Decode() needs Quadrangle vertices found by Detect() method whereas Detect() only returns a bool (that tells wether a QR code is detected or not) and we cannot access anything in a QRCodeDetector object.

Here is my current code for context :

```cs
Image<Bgr, Byte> img1 = new Image<Bgr, Byte>(@"C:\Users\Dacapo\source\repos\qrcode_reading\qrcode_reading\qr.jpg");
IInputArray img1arr = img1;
Mat pos = new Mat(1, 2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32S, 1);

QRCodeDetector detector = new QRCodeDetector();
bool decoded = detector.Detect(img1arr, pos); //this returns true
```

And here is qr.jpg :
[image: qr code to test the code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to their docs at: https://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/4.6.0/document/html/Methods_T_Emgu_CV_BarcodeDetector.htm there is now a DetectAndDecode() method which can take two overloads. Hope this helps. I am currently working on a similar implementation so I'll report any progress here.

Answer (score 0):

add these packages:

```
 <PackageReference Include="Emgu.CV" Version="4.8.1.5350" />
 <PackageReference Include="Emgu.CV.runtime.windows" Version="4.8.1.5350" />
```

when you upload image:

```
using var image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(ImageUrl);

// Detect QR code
var qrCodeDetector = new QRCodeDetector();

Mat points = new Mat(1, 2, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.DepthType.Cv32S, 1);
var detected = qrCodeDetector.Detect(image, points);

 if (detected)
     {
     // Decode QR code
     var decodedText = qrCodeDetector.Decode(image, points);
     Console.WriteLine($"Decoded QR code: {decodedText}");
 }
```